# Android: Get Emoji from EmojiconEditText

Tags: java, android, emoji

i am trying to implement Emojis into my app. Everything is working fine for now (Keyboard is showing up etc.) but i have problems getting the unicode out of the EmojiconEditText.

I am using https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

The result i get when i try EmojiconEditText.getText() is always �.
Does anyone know how i can get the unicode string out of the EmojiconEditText?

What i already tried: Setting HttpPost to UTF16, using getText() directly in the EditText, not an Editable and using .toString().

All had the result �

Comment: I am also getting the same issue. I have requested Ankush here at this link. Please do follow up on the same. https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon/issues/8

Comment: where are you trying to print these strings?

Comment: @Anukush, I tried to send the data to MySQL database via Web-service. In MySQL, it's storing as �

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you mentioned you are sending the text to MySQL, make sure you select collation as utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Make sure you have put utf8mb4_unicode_ci at the correct column/table.

Comment: This worked. Also, i removed any mysql_set_charset in PHP and edited the mysql server config file as mentioned in the link above.

Comment: hi ankush, emojis are pretty old. have you by any chance upgraded the library with new emojicons?